# Rails - Unable to access Instance variables in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Controller:

```
def store
  if params[:name].present? && params[:pass].present? && params[:cpass].present? && params[:role].present?
    @name = params[:name].downcase

    if CheckEmpName(@name) == 0     
      render "userexist"
      return
    end

    pass = params[:pass]
    cpass = params[:cpass]

    if pass != cpass                
      render "passerror"
      return
    end

    role = params[:role]

    @user = Employee.new(name: @name, password: pass, role: role)
    @user.save

  end
  render "success"
end
```

The above action renders the "success.html.erb" page when all the user inputs are valid. Instead if the username is already registered
or both the password and confirm password are not matched then it renders the appropriate error files which is "userexist.html.erb" or
"passerror.html.erb".

Problem:

I am able to access @name instance variable in success.html.erb file. But I am not able to access that in both of the error
html files. Why it is only accessible in "success" and not in "userexist" and "passerror". Why it is not accessible. And What I need to
do to access those variable in both of the error handling html pages ?

Comment: Show your views (working and non-working)

Comment: You shuld be using render 3 times, you should render only one and pass flash[:error] to them, or use partials. Even rails shows an error when you use render or redirect many times in a single method.

Comment: *"I am not able to access that in both of the error html files"* Where is this happening? I don't see where `userexist` or `passerror` are being rendered.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev. Thanks. I done my mistakes in my views. Instead of specifying "@name", I specified "@user". That is the mistake.

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos: this code will not produce "double render" error.

Comment: No because you used return everywhere. But it smells. You shouldn't have 3 renders and returns, that's untestable. But we aren't here to learn about code quality anyways.

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos: the rendering part is perfectly testable. `expect(response).to render_template('userexist')`. This code has problems, but multiple rendering ain't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You may explicitly pass whatever you want to access as `locals` hash parameter to call to `render`:

```
render "userexist", locals: { name: @name }
```

Now `name` will be passed through to underlying template.

Comment: Is it possible to send local variable instead of instance variable ?

Comment: Sure, the hash will be passed through as is, think about it as about plain ruby. One might put there whatever.